# How do i change Android App Name Text Color in a Transparent App Bar

Tags: java, android, colors, transparent, textcolor

I'd like to set my app name color to gray with a transparent app bar and an image background. However, app name color stayed white for some reason. Below is my code. Any recommendations? Thank you in advance!

```
1. Themes.xml
   

     <resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
        <!-- Base application theme. -->
        <style name="Theme.DailyBread" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
            <!-- Primary brand color. -->
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
            <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
            <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
            <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
            <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
            <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
            <!-- Status bar color. -->
            <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        </style>
        <style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.Transparent" parent="Theme.DailyBread">
            <item name="titleTextColor">@color/gray_dark</item>
            <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/gray_dark</item>
            <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
            <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
            <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
            <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
            <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
        </style>
    </resources>
    
 2. color.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <color name="purple_200">#FFBB86FC</color>
        <color name="purple_500">#FF6200EE</color>
        <color name="purple_700">#FF3700B3</color>
        <color name="teal_200">#FF03DAC5</color>
        <color name="teal_700">#FF018786</color>
        <color name="black">#FF000000</color>
        <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
        <color name="gray_dark">#696665</color>
        <color name="gary_light">#bdbab9</color>
    </resources>
```

Comment: Use toolbar instead of Actionbar

Answer (score 0):

Create your `toolbar.xml` file with background of `AppBarLayout` is `@null`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/general_appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Application Name"
            android:textSize="42sp"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

PS: you can also use `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` instead of `@null`.

**Result:**

[image: Transparent Toolbar]